# {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true} what is the use of this in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

After Installing mongoose

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});
```

What is the use of useNewUrlParser and useUnifiedToplogy ?

Comment: http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/3.6/api/global.html#MongoClientOptions

Answer (score 6):

According to [the documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/deprecations.html):

-->unifiedtopology  : DeprecationWarning: current Server Discovery and Monitoring engine is
deprecated, and will be removed in a future version. To use the new Server
Discover and Monitoring engine, pass option { useUnifiedTopology: true } to
the MongoClient constructor.

-->usenewurlparser :
DeprecationWarning: current URL string parser is deprecated, and will be
removed in a future version. To use the new parser, pass option
{ useNewUrlParser: true } to MongoClient.connect.